# Printing output with format (page x)-> in cpp

Tags: c++

Please provide the implementation of functions append, printList, and delete_evens as described in the comments. You will be dealing with a linked list of pages in which every node (page), is linked to its next and previous node (page) using next and prev pointers respectively. Please note the previous node of the first node (head) is NULL. In a similar way, the next of the last node will also be NULL.

The expected output is as follows:

```
Created PageList:
(page1)->(page2)->(page3)->(page4)->(page5)->(page6)->(page7)->(page8)->(page9)->(page10)->(page11)->(page12)->(page13)->(page14)->(page15)->(page16)->(page17)->(page18)->(page19)->(page20)->(page21)->(page22)->(page23)->(page24)->(page25)->(page26)->(page27)->(page28)->(page29)->(page30)->(page31)->(page32)->(page33)->(page34)->(page35)->(page36)->(page37)->(page38)->(page39)->(page40)->(page41)->(page42)->(page43)->(page44)->(page45)->(page46)->(page47)->(page48)->(page49)->(page50)->
Updated PageList:
(page1)->(page3)->(page5)->(page7)->(page9)->(page11)->(page13)->(page15)->(page17)->(page19)->(page21)->(page23)->(page25)->(page27)->(page29)->(page31)->(page33)->(page35)->(page37)->(page39)->(page41)->(page43)->(page45)->(page47)->(page49)->
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Created PageList:
(page)->1 (page)->2 (page)->3 (page)->4 (page)->5 (page)->6 (page)->7 (page)->8 (page)->9 (page)->10 (page)->11 (page)->12 (page)->13 (page)->14 (page)->15 (page)->16 (page)->17 (page)->18 (page)->19 (page)->20 (page)->21 (page)->22 (page)->23 (page)->24 (page)->25 (page)->26 (page)->27 (page)->28 (page)->29 (page)->30 (page)->31 (page)->32 (page)->33 (page)->34 (page)->35 (page)->36 (page)->37 (page)->38 (page)->39 (page)->40 (page)->41 (page)->42 (page)->43 (page)->44 (page)->45 (page)->46 (page)->47 (page)->48 (page)->49 (page)->50 
Updated PageList:
(page)->1 (page)->3 (page)->5 (page)->7 (page)->9 (page)->11 (page)->13 (page)->15 (page)->17 (page)->19 (page)->21 (page)->23 (page)->25 (page)->27 (page)->29 (page)->31 (page)->33 (page)->35 (page)->37 (page)->39 (page)->41 (page)->43 (page)->45 (page)->47 (page)->49
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Page {
public:
  int page_number = 0;
  string page_content = "";
  Page *next = NULL;
  Page *prev = NULL; // previous
};

class PageList {

public:
  Page *head = NULL; // point to the first page

  // append a page to the end of the list
  void append(int page_number, string page_content) {
    Page *first;
    first = new Page();
    first->page_content = page_content;
    first->next = NULL;
    first->prev = NULL;
    first->page_number = page_number;
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = first;
    } else {
      Page *second = head;
      while (second->next != NULL) {
        second = second->next;
      }
      second->next = first;
    }
  }

  // print all the elements of the list (pages) with the given format
  void print list(Page *node, bool forward) {
    while (node != NULL) {
      cout << node->page_content << " ";
      node = node->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  void delete_evens() { // delete the pages with even page_number
    Page *first = head;
    Page *q = NULL;
    while (first != NULL) {
      if (first->page_number % 2 == 0) {
        if (q == NULL) {
          head = first->next;
          first = first->next;
        } else {
          q->next = first->next;
          first->next = NULL;
          first = q->next;
        }
      } else {
        if (q == NULL) {
          q = first;
          first = first->next;
        } else {
          q = q->next;
          first = first->next;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  PageList(int pages) noexcept // consteructor
  {
    head = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
      append(i, "(page" + to_string(i));
    }
    cout << "Created PageList:" << endl;
    printList(head, true);
    delete_evens();
    cout << "Updated PageList:" << endl;
    printList(head, true);
  }
};

int main() {
  PageList list(50);
  return 0;
}
```

I believe that the error is somewhere in the line `append(i, "(page" + to_string(i));`

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should tab your code, is really hard to read

Comment: @Linus Will do..

Comment: The posted code is not going to create the output you say you're getting.

Comment: @DavidThornley could you please help? I am unsure what to do.

Comment: @KevalPatel, going to study some more?

Comment: @KevalPatel It's hard to recommend something without knowing what code you're working on.   Make sure the output and the source code agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
class Page {
public:
     int page_number = 0;
     string page_content = "";
     Page* next = NULL;
     Page* prev = NULL;// previous
};

class PageList {
public:
     Page* head=NULL; // point to the first page
  
// append a page to the end of the list
void append(int page_number, string page_content){
     Page* first;
     first=new Page();
     first->page_content = page_content;
     first->next=NULL;
     first->prev=NULL;
     first->page_number=page_number;
     if(head==NULL) {
        head=first;
}
else{
   Page* second=head;
   while(second->next != NULL) {
         second=second->next;
}

  second->next=first;

}
  
}

// print all the elements of the list (pages) with the given format
void printList(Page* node, bool forward) {
     while(node != NULL) {

     cout<<node->page_content<<""<<")->";;
     node=node->next;
}
  cout<<endl;
}

void delete_evens() // delete the pages with even page_number
{
     Page* first = head;
     Page* q=NULL;
     while(first != NULL)
{

     if(first->page_number % 2 == 0)

{
     if(q==NULL)
{
     head=first->next;
     first=first->next;
}
else
{
     q->next=first->next;
     first->next=NULL;
     first=q->next;
  
}
}
else
{
     
     if(q==NULL)

{
     q=first;
first=first->next;
}
else
{
     q=q->next;
     first=first->next;
}
  }
    }
      }

PageList(int pages) noexcept // consteructor
{
     head = NULL;

     for (int i=1;i<=pages;i++){

     append(i, "(page" + to_string(i));
}

     cout<< "Created PageList:" << endl;

     printList(head,true);

     delete_evens();

     cout<< "Updated PageList:" << endl;

     printList(head,true);
}
  };
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()

{

   PageList list(50);

return 0;

}
```